# Queueing calls to a slot in event loop processed in backwards order by Qt

Tags: c++, qt

In an application that I am working on I have a QLineEdit that is attached with a standard QObject::connect to a slot:

```
QObject::connect(m_searchBar, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),this,SLOT(slot_searchBar()));
```

As you can see it is connecting a textChanged signal to a slot of my creation. This slot looks like the following:

```
   void LibraryWidget::slot_searchBar() 
{
    QString stringToFind = m_searchBar->text();

    m_searchResults->clear();
    if(stringToFind.isEmpty())
    {
        //set stacked widget back to the library when no text in search bar 
        m_libraryAndSearch->setCurrentWidget(libTree);
    } 
    else 
    {
        //show the search results
        QFont headerFont;
        QTreeWidgetItem * searchingMsg = new QTreeWidgetItem;
        headerFont = searchingMsg->font(0);
        headerFont.setBold(false);
        headerFont.setItalic(true);
        searchingMsg->setText(0, "Searching...");
        searchingMsg->setFont(0, headerFont);
        Qt::ItemFlags currentState = searchingMsg->flags();
        Qt::ItemFlags noSelect = (!(Qt::ItemIsSelectable) & currentState);
        searchingMsg->setFlags(noSelect);
        m_searchResults->addTopLevelItem(searchingMsg);
        m_libraryAndSearch->setCurrentWidget(m_searchResults);
        //m_searchThread->setTerminateAndWait();    
        //m_searchThread->beginThread(stringToFind);
        int testTwo = 0;
        for(int testInt = 0; testInt < 1000000000; testInt++)
        {
            testTwo++;
        }
        int testingThree = 0;
    }
}
```

which is hopefully of limited importance but it is probably best to show you just in case the root of the problem lies here.

If I type a string into the search bar, which is the QLineEdit in question, (pretty quickly) and look at what is going on with the debugger attached (Visual Studio 2010) then I see the most bizarre thing:

If I already have "Jake" in the search bar (from a previous search, typed slowly) then quickly type "gh" then the `stringToFind` value is "Jakegh" on the first run through the slot and then "Jakeg" on the second run through.

It is as though Qt has added the signal emissions to a stack instead of a queue and then served them back to the event loop in reverse order.

The question is: does anyone have a clue what is going on here? Has anyone experienced similar results?

Qt version 4.7

The code as it stands is just to recreate the problem, it doesn't do anything. int testTwo -> int testingThree is only there to slow the code down.

Thanks...

**EDIT**
The same behaviour was observed when the string was passed in to the slot as a function argument. The line

```
QString stringToFind = m_searchBar->text();
```

was an attempt to debug and circumvent the phenomenon.

**EDIT TWO**

I have tried to recreate this at home. Building Qt from the terminal on Mac OS X 10.7 so no debugger available. I am using a very simple class and main.cpp that has the same format as the above and I can't make Qt serve me the letters in reverse order. I can make it miss signals though. I have connected a line edit to a text edit such that every time the text changes in the line edit it is printed to the text edit using `QTextEdit::append(( const QString & text ))`.

For example if I type "N", "e", "w" then "N", "Ne", "New" should be printed to the text edit. However, sometimes it just prints "N", "New" instead. I have a for loop slowing everything down and have to hit the keys **really** fast.

The system that caused the phenomenon to occur first time around was necessarily infinitely more complicated than the one I have built, it was running in debug and was running slowly. Still don't get why that would cause the behaviour though and it most definitely did!

Comment: Even if Qt did add it to a stack (it doesn't), it still wouldn't result in the behaviour you're describing. You're not using the value in the signal: you're using the current value in the object.

There are a few things that make me wonder. Is it a queued connection or a direct connection? And is the slot object in the same thread as the signal emitter?

Comment: @Slavik81 Yes, you make a good point about getting the text from the box directly. This was in an attempt to circumvent the described behaviour and was still happening when I sent the string as an argument to the slot (QString &). It was originally in a multi-threaded environment but I removed the threading and could still recreate the phenomenon (as shown above). It is an AutoConnection which defaults to a Qt::DirectConnection in single threaded environments I believe...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is your delay loop, supposedly emulating what an actual search does. That's precisely the wrong way to approach it. The search should run asynchronously, in a separate QObject that you can then move to a separate thread. Simply connect a signal in your searchbar to the searcher object, and then when the searcher has new results, it should signal back.

Your testing delay loop should be replaced by something like `QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(fakeResults()))`, where the code in the slot calls relevant slot in your GUI with some fake results.

I'd suggest you also attach a "watcher" object to the QLineEdit, to monitor things. Here's how:

```
// in some file, say foo.cpp
class Watcher : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  QPointer<QLineEdit*> const edit;
public:
  Watcher(QLineEdit * ed, QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent), edit(ed) {
    connect(ed, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), SLOT(monitor(QString)));
  }
public slots:
  void monitor(const QString & str) {
    qDebug("Line edit signals text: %s", str.toLocal8Bit().constData());
    if (! edit.isNull() && edit->text() != str) {
      qDebug("... but line edit has text %s", edit->text().toLocal8Bit().constData());
    }
  }
}

#include "foo.moc" // replace 'foo' with actual name of the file (sans .cpp)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have done in the actual application but it was too much to post in a question. The other thing to note is that the code as it is above AND with the signal slot set up as per the EDIT in the question reproduces the results...any ideas?

Comment: Will look at it. If you remove the delay loop, do you still get those results?

Comment: I have added an edit to the question that may help a bit. I have a feeling that a very thorough look at the actual code in the application and a good understanding of how the nuts and bolts of the event loop are put together will get to the bottom of this. Removing the delay loop means it is possible to get the results but it is way less likely as one needs to hit the keys fast enough that the loop can't fully execute before the next message is sent. When I do a release build it is way too fast to ever see the phenomenon. HTH, would love to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the problem with the loop? In the actual application, when I fist saw this happening, the loop was a call to a separate thread which did a search and then posted an event back which was dealt with in a separate function in the same class (QEvent one obviously). Thinking that it was the threads messing things up I ditched them in favour of something simpler (for loop) and saw the same thing. Surely using a loop and getting the results simplifies the problem domain and makes it more understandable/narrows down the causes? Not having a go, just interested...

Answer (score 0):

Don't grab the text, use the QString & in the signal.

```
QObject::connect(m_searchBar, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),this,SLOT(slot_searchBar(const QString &)));
```

and then later

```
void LibraryWidget::slot_searchBar(const QString &stringToFind) {
...
```

As for the reason that you're seeing your behaviour, I can almost gaurantee that it's a Qt::QueuedConnection at some point. You can have QueuedConnection in single threaded code as well, it will just wait until the next event loop to execute the code in it. Check out the details of it: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum.

Comment: That's not it, at least not very likely. Everything here runs on the same GUI thread, so everything will be serialized. It doesn't matter if the connection is queued or not. There's no way for a QLineEdit to emit a signal with new results, and a subsequently called `text()` to return old results.

Comment: @suslik That is what I was doing and then tried grabbing the result from the bar directly to see if that stopped it. Same thing happens both ways round though.